# Cuda thrust::device_vector get pointer from specific range

Tags: c++, vector, cuda, thrust

I have a vector of vectors:

```
thrust::device_vector weights_;
```

which is a continuous amount of memory, where every **w** items,
represent a vector.

In one of my functions, I pass as parameters the begin and end of that range, like so:

```
 __host__ ann::d_vector ann::prop_layer (
                                           unsigned int weights_begin,
                                           unsigned int weights_end,
                                           ann::d_vector & input
                                        ) const
```

and then, I go and copy into a new vector that range,
and then get a raw pointer which I can use in a kernel:

```
thrust::device_vector<float> weights ( weights_.begin() + weights_begin,
                                       weights_.begin() + weights_end );

float * weight_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast( weights.data() );

some_kernel<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>( weight_ptr, weight.size() );
```

1. Can I get a pointer from that range, without first copying it to a new vector? That seems like a waste of copy-realloc to me.
2. In case I can't get a pointer from that range, can I at least assign a vector to that range, without copying the actual values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I get a pointer from that range, without first copying it to a new vector? That seems like a waste of copy-realloc to me.

Yes, you can get a pointer to that range.

```
float * weight_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast( weights_.data() ) + weights_begin;
```

> In case I can't get a pointer from that range, can I at least assign a vector to that range, without copying the actual values?

No,  a thrust vector cannot be instantiated "on top" of existing data.

Comment: That simple huh? Thanks !

Comment: *error: no suitable conversion function from "thrust::device_ptr<const float>" to "float *" exists*
Do I need to *thrust::raw_pointer_cast* it first?

Comment: This seems to require that I either remove *const* from the methods, or cast to const float *, but it works, thanks for the help :-)